Entering the Philippines as spouse of a citizen
I am a dual UK / Irish citizen and my wife is a dual UK / Philippine citizen.
If I enter the Philippines without declaring this connection then I get allowed a typical 3 weeks (*).  However, if we enter together then I am allowed a year.  In the past, it was easy to walk up to the immigration desk together and hand over our passports together and I would be granted a year without asking.  On our most recent trip, the queuing system was different with a single queue and you were ushered to a free desk when one became available.  They did not like multiple people going up together.  So, I ended up at a different desk and my status was not obvious.  I was given just the standard short duration for any UK visitor.  I did not make an issue as we only planned to stay a week.
If we go again and I would like to stay longer, what is the best strategy?  Just explain and insist on  going together?  I guess that I could apply for a visa in advance but that is a bit annoying as it used to be so easy.  The ideal would be some official acknowledgement that I am married to a Philippine citizen and entitled to one year.  If such a thing were available and could be used multiple times then it would be worth the effort to get one.
Note that we are not planning to live or work there.  It is just that now that I am retired, we can take longer vacations.
(*) I think that it is 3 weeks but it might be 2 or 4, I forget.  It was certainly sufficient for our one week visit but not for a multiple month visit as we might make in the future.

Do you have a Philippine marriage certificate?

@lambshaanxy No, and the one that we have is not in English or even the Latin script.  This has caused problems for my wife in the Philippines.  Some authorities want a translation by the Philippine Embassy in Thailand.  In the past at immigration, no one has asked for it, just arriving together with the same surname was enough.

My wife and I had to register our marriage in her country of citizenship before the UN (her employer) would recognize me as her spouse.  It was certainly a hassle, but not that bad, and once it's done, it's done.  Still, having the Philippine certificate would be of only limited use if you also have to prove that you're traveling with her.  I would probably focus, at first, on how to get the people running the queueing system to allow you to approach together.  It seems highly odd that they discourage it. At least you could pretend that one of you is infirm and requires the other's help.

Does the UK or Ireland offer the possibility of including your spouse's name in your passport?  If so, would it be possible to do it with less hassle than getting a translation of your certificate from the Philippine embassy in Thailand?

@phoog That hasn't been possible for a very long time.  I remember as a kid going to Spain with just my father's passport for him, mum, and 4 kids.  Mum's photo was in the passport but just names and dates of birth for us kids.  Does anywhere still offer that?

@phoog On the queuing, I did not press it.  I started to walk with my wife and I was waved back.  If I had planned to stay longer then I would have spoken up but I saw no need for a fuss.  I saw the same happen to a few other couples who also just accepted it.  Oddly the usher did not speak at all; he just waved us back.

@phoog Travelling with her, that's an interesting question.  For the EU, my wife will only be allowed to exceed the usual 90/180 limit if she is with me.  I have no idea whether there is a similar rule for the Philippines.  In fact, I don't know the exact rules.  I have just noticed that, provided that we present our passports together, I am given one year.  I have not entered the Philippines without her since before we were married.  Our son gets one year even if he enters alone with his UK passport but that shows his place of birth as Manila.

@phoog and badjohn: I know that thailand stamps the passport with "thai wife"/"thai husband" (see right-middle in that pic) if you have married a thai citizen. Maybe phillipines also offers that?

@ave That is what I would like but I've not found it or heard of it.  My friends married to Thais have not mentioned it.  I'll ask them.

@badjohn the Netherlands offers the option to list one's spouse in the passport.  Nobody imagines that it is any longer possible for a couple to travel together using a single such passport, but it does serve as evidence of the relationship.  I suppose that it is possible in other countries as well.

@phoog Interesting, i have not heard of that.  I'll research it for the UK and Ireland.
